# Piping AudioKit Microphone to Google Speech-to-Text

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, audiokit

I'm trying to get `AudioKit` to pipe the microphone to Google's Speech-to-Text API as seen [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Swift) but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it.

To prepare the audio for the Speech-to-Text engine, you need to set up the encoding and pass it through as chunks. In the example Google uses, they use Apple's `AVFoundation`, but I'd like to use AudioKit so I can preform some pre-processing such as cutting of low amplitudes etc.

I believe the right way to do this is to use a `Tap`:

First, I should match the format by:

```
var asbd = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
asbd.mSampleRate = 16000.0
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 2
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 2
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16

AudioKit.format = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &asbd)!
```

Then create a tap such as:

```
open class TestTap {
    internal let bufferSize: UInt32 = 1_024

    @objc public init(_ input: AKNode?) {
        input?.avAudioNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: bufferSize, format: AudioKit.format) { buffer, _ in

         // do work here

        }
    }
}
```

But I wasn't able to identify the right way of handling this data to be sent to the Google Speech-to-Text API via the method [`streamAudioData`](http://%20%20func%20streamAudioData(_%20audioData:%20NSData,%20completion:%20@escaping%20SpeechRecognitionCompletionHandler)%20%7B) in real-time with `AudioKit` but perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?

**UPDATE:**

I've created a `Tap` as such:

```
open class TestTap {

    internal var audioData =  NSMutableData()
    internal let bufferSize: UInt32 = 1_024

    func toData(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> NSData {
        let channelCount = 2  // given PCMBuffer channel count is
        let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData, count: channelCount)
        return NSData(bytes: channels[0], length:Int(buffer.frameCapacity * buffer.format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame))
    }

    @objc public init(_ input: AKNode?) {

        input?.avAudioNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: bufferSize, format: AudioKit.format) { buffer, _ in
            self.audioData.append(self.toData(buffer: buffer) as Data)

            // We recommend sending samples in 100ms chunks (from Google)
            let chunkSize: Int /* bytes/chunk */ = Int(0.1 /* seconds/chunk */
                * AudioKit.format.sampleRate /* samples/second */
                * 2 /* bytes/sample */ )

            if self.audioData.length > chunkSize {
                SpeechRecognitionService
                    .sharedInstance
                    .streamAudioData(self.audioData,
                                     completion: { response, error in
                                        if let error = error {
                                            print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                            SpeechRecognitionService.sharedInstance.stopStreaming()
                                        } else if let response = response {
                                            print(response)
                                        }
                    })
                self.audioData = NSMutableData()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad:`, I'm setting AudioKit up with:

```
AKSettings.sampleRate = 16_000
AKSettings.bufferLength = .shortest
```

However, Google complains with:

`ERROR: Audio data is being streamed too fast. Please stream audio data approximately at real time.`

I've tried changing multiple parameters such as the chunk size to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/audiokit/set$20format%7Csort:date/audiokit/NoTg9K2rRy8/h9rV60IIBQAJ).

Final code for my `Tap` is:

```
open class GoogleSpeechToTextStreamingTap {

internal var converter: AVAudioConverter!

@objc public init(_ input: AKNode?, sampleRate: Double = 16000.0) {

    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)!

    self.converter = AVAudioConverter(from: AudioKit.format, to: format)
    self.converter?.sampleRateConverterAlgorithm = AVSampleRateConverterAlgorithm_Normal
    self.converter?.sampleRateConverterQuality = .max

    let sampleRateRatio = AKSettings.sampleRate / sampleRate
    let inputBufferSize = 4410 //  100ms of 44.1K = 4410 samples.

    input?.avAudioNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(inputBufferSize), format: nil) { buffer, time in

        let capacity = Int(Double(buffer.frameCapacity) / sampleRateRatio)
        let bufferPCM16 = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(capacity))!

        var error: NSError? = nil
        self.converter?.convert(to: bufferPCM16, error: &error) { inNumPackets, outStatus in
            outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
            return buffer
        }

        let channel = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bufferPCM16.int16ChannelData!, count: 1)
        let data = Data(bytes: channel[0], count: capacity * 2)

        SpeechRecognitionService
            .sharedInstance
            .streamAudioData(data,
                             completion: { response, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    SpeechRecognitionService.sharedInstance.stopStreaming()
                                } else if let response = response {
                                    print(response)
                                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can likely record using AKNodeRecorder, and pass along the buffer from the resulting AKAudioFile to the API. If you wanted more real-time, you could try installing a tap on the avAudioNode property of the AKNode you want to record and pass the buffers to the API continuously.

However, I'm curious why you see the need for pre-processing - I'm sure the Google API is plenty optimized for recordings produced by the sample code you noted.

I've had a lot of success / fun with the iOS [Speech API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech). Not sure if there's a reason you want to go with the Google API, but I'd consider checking it out and seeing if it might better serve your needs if you haven't already.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @cgmaier - thanks for responding. I want to pre-process because despite using an attached cardioid microphone, I'm picking up the person next to the user. The speech-to-text system is highly sensitive it seems and I want to cut off lower signals.